# libav - undefined reference to 'av_frame_alloc' and more

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I am trying to compile this tutorial from the libav doc: [link](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2decoding__encoding_8c-example.html)

I changed nothing on the code!

But when I compile it with:

```
gcc test.c -lavformat -lswscale -lavdevice -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lpthread -lm -o example
```

I get these errors:

```
undefined reference to `check_sample_fmt'
undefined reference to `select_sample_rate'
undefined reference to `select_channel_layout'
undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc'
undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
```

Searching Dr.google I read that it maybe has something to do with the linking order of the libs. But I did not found the correct one yet?!

EDIT:
this 'possible dublicate' seems not to be related to my problem

Comment: Thank you Dayal, I have allready seen that topic! But do not think this is related to my problem

Comment: I also tryed it with this order: gcc -o example test.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lfdk-aac -lao -lavdevice -lavresample -lpthread -lm             Now i only have undefined reference to 'av_frame_alloc and av_frame_free'

Comment: Are you sure you need to link with all those libraries? That example program compiled fine for me with just `gcc test.c -lavutil -lm -lavcodec -o example`

Comment: Thank you @szx, sadly i still get some undefined reference errors. Maybe this can help. I am using libav(11.4) with ./configure --disable-shared --enable-static I copied the example code for 'audio decoding' out of the example in the doc folder. It is a newer version of the example i posted abouth(i was just able to find this old one online)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg comes with an Makefile for the examples. I took this one and simply used it for my libav examples. [Link](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/Makefile)

Answer (score 3):

You probably are running an old code with a newer version of FFmpeg.
Ffmpeg changed some functions names, some create some deprecated warnings while others create errors.

According to the official [Ffmpeg github](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/APIchanges#L1097):

```
av_frame_alloc(), av_frame_unref() and av_frame_free() now can and should be 
used instead of avcodec_alloc_frame(), avcodec_get_frame_defaults() and avcodec_free_frame() respectively
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't apply in your case, but you get a similar issue if you try to use ffmpeg from C++.

```cpp
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

int main() {
  av_frame_alloc();
}
```

Unfortunately the ffmpeg headers do not have the proper `extern "C" {` wrappers so you have to do it yourself.

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

int main() {
  av_frame_alloc();
}
```

Comment: Ah that was actually my issue. Of course, those libraries should have the `extern "C" ...` inside their headers. Grrr...

Answer (score 0):

You are using GNU toolchain. On Windows, I have seen that sometimes MSVC linker also produces .lib files when generating shared/dynamic .dll libraries. These .lib only holds symbol information needed during linking step but have have no actual machine code. As a result, you still have to add them to linker input. In Visual studio they can be added to "Project -> properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies" For example: Append the following to the above path "avformat.lib; avcodec.lib; avutil.lib". This would solve the undefined symbol issue in the question. I am not sure how different, things are with GNU. But I hope this can help any Windows user facing a similar problem.
On Windows do these three things:

1. Add all include files directories to "Project -> properties -> VC++ Directories -> General -> Include Directories"
2. Add all .lib files to "Project -> properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies"
3. Copy all the .dll files where your executable is produced.

Answer (score 0):

in my case that was due to problem in linking libraries to the project. I used `target_link_options` rather than `target_link_libraries`.

to summarize all necessary steps

1. install ffmpeg by standard way described [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md)
2. install package-config to locate its package
3. use the following code to link libraries to your code as a nice example is in [here](https://github.com/bmewj/video-app/blob/master/lib/FFmpeg/CMakeLists.txt)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(FFmpeg)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(AVCODEC     REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavcodec)
pkg_check_modules(AVFORMAT    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavformat)
pkg_check_modules(AVFILTER    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavfilter)
pkg_check_modules(AVDEVICE    REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice)
pkg_check_modules(AVUTIL      REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libavutil)
pkg_check_modules(SWRESAMPLE  REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswresample)
pkg_check_modules(SWSCALE     REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libswscale)

add_library(FFmpeg INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)

target_link_libraries(FFmpeg INTERFACE
    PkgConfig::AVCODEC
    PkgConfig::AVFORMAT
    PkgConfig::AVFILTER
    PkgConfig::AVDEVICE
    PkgConfig::AVUTIL
    PkgConfig::SWRESAMPLE
    PkgConfig::SWSCALE
)
```